# Android Studio prompts to upgrade AGP to a version that is already used

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I wonder if I misunderstand something fundamentally.

My project build.gradle has:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

This is the only place with the AGP version. Android Studio Hedgehog prompts to upgrade AGP to 8.2.2. However, it also says the upgrade step is blocked:

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?